# Convert absolute path to relative path for photo in Java

Tags: java, selenium, relative-path, sikuli

I try to give a relative path to the popup.jpg file but all the time it crashes that it does not find the file and the internet did not give me an answer so I decided to ask here

It's my code:

```
public class WrongDate
{
    public static void main(String[] args) throws MalformedURLException, InterruptedException, FindFailed
      {
     
 //String page = "C:\\Users\\kamil\\OneDrive\\Dokumenty\\eclipse - proj\\Project\\popup.jpg"; 
       
 String page = "./eclipse - proj/Project/popup.jpg";  
        WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();
        
        driver.navigate().to("https://www.fandom.com/register?redirect=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.fandom.com%2Fexplore-pl%3Fuselang%3Dpl%26cb%3D1618719439872");
        driver.findElement(By.xpath("/html/body/div[1]/div/div/div[2]/div[2]")).click();
        driver.findElement(By.id("signupEmail")).sendKeys("");
        driver.findElement(By.id("signupUsername")).sendKeys("");
        driver.findElement(By.id("signupPassword")).sendKeys("");
        driver.findElement(By.name("birthdate")).click();
        driver.findElement(By.name("month")).sendKeys("89");
        driver.findElement(By.name("day")).sendKeys("48");
        driver.findElement(By.name("year")).sendKeys("1567");
        driver.findElement(By.id("signupSubmit")).click();    
        Screen a = new Screen();
        a.find(page);
        //String b = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id=\"signupForm\"]/div[3]/small")).getText();

        System.out.println(page);
      }
};
```

Comment: do you get any error?

Answer (score 0):

```
String currentWorkingDir = System.getProperty("user.dir");
```

will give you current working directory, in this case your project folder will be current working directory.

all you have to do is to put (**let's say image.jpg in your project folder)** and define the name like this :

```
String imageName = abc.jpg
```

and use relative path like this :

```
a.find(currentWorkingDir + "\\" + imageName);
```

Comment: I've tried, it doesn't work or I'm doing something wrong.                                          
 String X = System.getProperty("Project");
String page = "popup.jpg";                                                                                   
 a.find(X + "\\" + page);

Comment: You need to write user.dir instead of Project in system.getProperty call